# Sorting a list of objects by two different criteria in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, sorting, comparator

I'm working on a Kotlin application where I have the following class:

```
data class Schedule(
    val id: Int,
    val date: LocalDate,
    val examCodes: List<String>
)
```

I have a List and need to sort it by two different criteria:

Firstly, the schedules with the most number of examCodes should come first.

Secondly, the ones with the earliest date should come first.

This means that a Schedule with more examCodes and the closest date should be listed first.

For example, given the list of schedules:

```
val schedules = listOf(
    Schedule(id=1, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-05"), examCodes = listOf("A")),
    Schedule(id=2, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-06"), examCodes = listOf("B")),
    Schedule(id=3, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-07"), examCodes = listOf("C")),
    Schedule(id=4, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-10"), examCodes = listOf("A", "B")),
    Schedule(id=5, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-15"), examCodes = listOf("B", "C")),
    Schedule(id=6, date = LocalDate.parse("2023-07-24"), examCodes = listOf("C", "B", "A"))
)
```

The expected result would be:

```
    Schedule(id=4, date = 2023-07-10, examCodes = ["A", "B"]), // 2 exams, earliest date
    Schedule(id=5, date = 2023-07-15, examCodes = ["B", "C"]), // 2 exams, later date
    Schedule(id=6, date = 2023-07-24, examCodes = ["C", "B", "A"]), // 3 exams, even later date
    Schedule(id=1, date = 2023-07-05, examCodes = ["A"]), // 1 exam
    Schedule(id=2, date = 2023-07-06, examCodes = ["B"]), // 1 exam
    Schedule(id=3, date = 2023-07-07, examCodes = ["C"]) // 1 exam
```

I didn't find a way to satisfy both conditions at the same time while using built-in Kotlin sorting functions. How can this be achieved in Kotlin?

Already tried:

```
val sortedSchedules = schedules.sortedWith(
    compareBy<Schedule> { it.date }.thenByDescending { it.examCodes.size }
)
```

and

```
val sortedSchedules = schedules.sortedWith(
    compareByDescending<Schedule> { it.examCodes.size }.thenBy { it.date }
)
```

But neither returned the expected output.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the ordering you described. You said you want schedules with the most exams first, but then you put 2 exams before 3 exams. How is this correct?

Comment: I would like a combination of sorting criteria. The schedule id 6 contains the most exams but has furthest date so thats why i considered the schedule id 4 first

Comment: You need to formalize your expected order. You can't just say: "let's sort by both of them at the same time". Even as a human I don't understand what's your expected order. You expect id5 to come before id6, and what if I think it should be the other way around because of the number of exams?

Comment: 6 has 1 more exam than 5, but is 9 days later, so you put it second. 5 has 1 more exam then 1, and is 10 days later, so you put it... first. What's the logic behind this?